# Day trip to Shropshire Hills from Birmingham

Tags: public-transport, hiking, england

I will spend a weekend in Birmingham 3 weeks from now and I have no plans for Monday. I'd prefer to spend the day outdoors hiking, so I looked on the map and found Shropshire Hills AONB around 40 kms to the west.

I need to be back in Birmingham in the evening (have a plane back home at 21:30), I don't mind having to wake up early. What are the ways to get from Birmingham to Shropshire Hills by public transport (I'd prefer to not have to rent a car as I have no experience with driving on the left side of the road)? How much time will I spend travelling there?

Also, is the area better suited to hiking or biking? If biking is a good choice, is it possible to rent a bike there?

Comment: Not an answer, because I only have a link. See [car free walks](http://www.shropshiresgreatoutdoors.co.uk/walking/search/?keywords=&nearest=&distance=&routecatlist%5B%5D=car-free-walks&search2=Search)

Comment: The area is good for both hiking and biking.  There are plenty of bike rental places in the area, just search for "Church Stretton bike hire" :)

Comment: Also consider canal towpaths as Birmingham has many

Comment: @IanRingrose I would recommend a canal towpath walk for someone who wants to hike and is already in B'ham, but the OP specifically asked about the Shropshire Hills.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are frequent trains from Birmingham New Street to Church Stretton (via Shrewsbury) They are operated by Arriva Wales and London Midland.

Church Stretton is a quaint small market town typical of England in the Shropshire Hills which has easy walking access to the surrounding area. The area was known as little Switzerland in the Victorain era. The [Shropshire Way](http://www.shropshiresgreatoutdoors.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/shropshire-way-overview-map.jpg) passes through the village which is popular for walkers especially in the summer months.

Although there are bike routes through the area from experience I would say Shropshire was more popular for walkers given the hilly terrain than cycling.

Comment: I am a Shropshire gal and personally prefer cycling the area :)

Comment: I cycle from Staffordshire into Shropshire especially for the hills...